# Sorting installed apps in android?

Tags: android, sorting

I am able to get the list of all installed apps and their properties in an arraylist using
. I would like to filter the apps according to some inputs from user like

Video Players
Music Players
Games

etc.. , is there some property that provides this type of detail or is the only method to 
maintain a seperate table, although this is kind of impossible as the list of available apps at the playstore is almost endless...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> is there some property that provides this type of detail

No.

> although this is kind of impossible as the list of available apps at the playstore is almost endless

Correct. Hence, what you want is "kind of impossible".